# Adding and positioning eye to input field of password

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on Node.js project. I'm trying to add eye using Bootstrap to input field of password to see it. Here is the code of my input field:

```
  <div class="container">
        <form action='/register' method='post'>
            <h1 class="text-center">Enter data for form</h1>
            /* some other fields */
            <div class="form-group input-group">
                <input class="form-control item" type="password" name="password" id="password"
                minlength="8" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^\da-zA-Z]).{8,}$" id="password" placeholder="Password" required autocomplete="off">
                <i class="far fa-eye-slash" id="togglePassword"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-center">
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block save-info"
              type="submit">Register </button>
            </div>
        </form>
   </div>
```

The problem is actually with positioning of eye. Here is all necessary css styles:

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  padding:50px 0;
}

.container form, .hello {
  max-width:900px;
  padding:20px 30px;
  border-radius:10px;
  box-shadow:4px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #FFFACD;
}

.container .form-group {
  border-radius:10px;
  margin-bottom:25px;
  padding:5px 10px;
}

.container .save-info {
  border-radius:20px;
  padding:10px 20px;
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:bold;
  background-color:#3f93ff;
  border:none;
  color:white;
  margin-top:10px;
}


.container .text-center {
  font-size: xx-large;
  color:#154360;
}
 
#togglePassword {
  position: relative;
/*  left: 85%;*/
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

So, i tried to use togglePassword identifier like this, I received the result that eye adding after input field and it looks horrible. I also tried such code:

```
#togglePassword {
      position: absolute;
      left: 92%;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
```

Here, when I start entering password, the eye just disappears and it seems wrong logic. Can anybody suggest better solution or any ideas to make this eye look comfortable and respectable for people, please? I should be able to click on it in order to show/hide password.

Comment: `<div class="form-group input-group">` this div needs `position: relative`

Comment: @Konrad, it changes nothing, unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed some details on how to use the bootstrap input group correctly. Add two wrappers with the CSS classes *input-group-append* and *input-group-text* around your icon. If you want to have an icon on the right side of your input group your code should look like this (using bootstrap 4):

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username">
     <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text">
           <span class="far fa-eye-slash"></span>
        </span>
     </div>
</div>
```

You do not need the CSS code for #togglePassword.